# Phpunit giving No such file or directory on laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, phpunit, homestead

I just cloned a fresh version of laravel 5.5 and whenever i run .vendor/bin/phpunit on it I get

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘sh\r’: No such file or directory
```

I have tried different vairants of the command but ti still doesnt work.What confuses me is that the smae command runs on another 5.5 installation in the same folder
any ideas pls?

Comment: I'd start by removing `vendor` entirely and doing a fresh `composer install`. It looks to me like you've got an inadvertent line break somewhere, most likely from opening up files and accidentally hitting the wrong key at some point.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks so much that worked.Perhaps you can add that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the vendor folder and reinstall it using composer install.